# How to display only DATE part on View in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime, format

I'm trying to display only date part on my view, value I'm getting from database is pretty big and I really don't need informations like hrs, mns, seconds etc, I'm only interested in date, for example I would like to display only :

```
17/04/2017
```

And this is what I've tried so far:

```
<td>
       @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => ((DateTime)item.ValidFrom).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"))
</td>
<td>
       @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => ((DateTime)item.ValidTo).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"))
</td>
```

Here is the DateType of my Properties:

```
public System.DateTime ValidFrom { get; set; }
public Nullable<System.DateTime> ValidTo { get; set;
```

And here is the issue I get:
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Just Output Directly**

Instead of using the `DisplayFor()` helper method, you might consider just outputting the values directly if that would work for you:

```
<td>
   @modelItem.ValidFrom.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
</td>
<td>
   @modelItem.ValidTo?.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
</td>
```

**Consider ViewModel-Level Formatting**

Another possibly better option, would be performing this within your ViewModel itself as opposed to within the View:

```
public System.DateTime ValidFrom { get; set; }
public Nullable<System.DateTime> ValidTo { get; set; }

// These will be formatted versions of the properties specifically for output
public string FormattedFrom => ValidFrom.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
public string FormattedTo => ValidTo?.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") ?? "Present";
```

And then simply use those properties instead:

```
<td>
   @Model.FormattedFrom
</td>

<td>
   @Model.FormattedTo
</td>
```

Comment: This is cool I will accept answer soon, but what's gonna happen when I upadate my model from database than stuffs I added in my class will be lost, how could I solve this, somehow with partial classes or whatever?

Comment: and when I apply this code I am getting issue : "ValidTo" is property but is used like a type?

Comment: Those properties `FormattedFrom` and `FormattedTo` are essentially only getters, and thus will only use whatever data is present in the model itself, so you should be safe moving forward with that code. Additionally, there was a syntax error within the previous `FormattedTo` declaration, which should be resolved now.

Comment: outputting the values directly might work for me, in first case ValidFrom is displayed clear, but in second case when I add " ? " than it display this : 31.12.3000 0:00:00?.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")) ....

Comment: It may not like the newer C# syntax, try this `@(modelItem.ValidTo.HasValue ? modelItem.ValidTo.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") : "Present")`.

Comment: check for edit please. We have issue because it's nullable?

Comment: Doh! Here ya go: `@(Model.ValidTo.HasValue ? Model.ValidTo.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") : "Present")`. You can [see a working example of this in action here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/pSRXHa) as well.

Comment: now it works, and what does this mean, when there is no value there will be string written "Present"?

Comment: Correct. You can easily change that to whatever you'd like or simply leave it as an empty string. It's an example of the [ternary operator](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/18/operators/6029/ternary-operator#t=201704172148518466496).

Comment: Thank you @Rion for the back to basics answer.

Comment: help me. [Help me]   (https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/131982/solo-mostrar-fecha-en-una-tabla-en-la-view)

Answer (score 2):

The solution might not be great in looking but I tried it and working for me.
You can try and use it for faster and temporary time.

```
@Html.FormatValue("yyy-MM-dd", item.date.ToString("yyy-MM-dd"))
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
<dd>
      @Convert.ToDateTime(Model.insertDateTimeFiled).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")
</dd>
```

If you only write:

```
Model.insertDateTimeFiled.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")
```

it trows "No overload for method 'ToString()' takes 1 argument